# MVC equilvelant of repeater with multiple form elements and checkbox to select

Tags: model-view-controller, repeater, checkboxlist

I need to replicate the functionality you get with an asp repeater that contains checkboxes, textboxes, and the occasional dropdownlist in an MVC application.  Om traditional webforms you get a postback event and its pretty easy to get at all the controls and their values associated with the checkbox (id).

Anybody have any good suggestions on how to get the values back on a post for the items that have the checkbox checked.  I am able to get some arrays back in the FormCollection (and even a strongly typed view) but I have not been able to figure out a good way to link the values effectivly.

All rows have a checkbox and a textbox, some rows also have a dropdownlist

To further explain...
row 1 has a checkbox and a textbox
row 2 has a checkbox a textbox, and a dropdown list.

if the user selects row 1 and 2, I need to get the values for all the form elements (for some calculations).  Also,  I haven't come up with a good method of handling validation errors.

any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do would be to iterate the collection for which you would have a repeater for. Using Razor syntax:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
<table>
@for (var i = 0; i < Models.Items.Count; i++) {
<tr>
<td>
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => Model.Items[i].SomeBool)
</td>
<td>
  @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.Items[i].SomeString)
</td>
</tr>
}
</table>
<button type="submit">Go</button>
}
```

Then a controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel viewModel) {
 // view model will be bound to values in form
}
```

Assuming the the Model in the view is of type MyViewModel. Once you have a sense of how this works you can look into [ASP.NET MVC grid frameworks](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=asp.net%20mvc%20grid).

Comment: The issue isn't in the creation of the html but rather the extraction of the selected values and ensuring that only the elements that are associated with the selected checkbox are used.  When the form posts, all the elements with the same name property are sent to the server as an array.  Its possible to just iterate through the checkbox array and for each element that is true, find the corresponding element in the textbox array and the dropdownlist array.  Problem is the ddl isnt on every record so the array elements are different